# Why are some country names in red?

Tags: xcom-enemy-within

When I select my starting country in XCOM: Enemy Within, why are some of the country names written in red?

[image: Country selection screen]

Comment: Do you have the tutorial enabled? It's been a while since I've played the game, but I think that North American and Europe are the recommended locations.

Comment: Yes I have the tutorial enabled

Comment: @LeoS. I think it's fair to mark this as a duplicate since Enemy Unknown and Enemy Within are so similar.